# Equate 2 Lists with different types/data models

Tags: java, android

I have 2 lists:

```
List<User1> users;
List<User2> users_;
```

Data Models  **User1** and  **User2** are completely similar except for their class names. They have been named differently only because i use them in a heterogeneous adapter and use instance of to ascertain view type

I would like to equate users to users_ at some point. How can i achieve this as simple type casting doesn't seem to work here:

EDIT:

User1 (which is the Same as User2 except for class name)

```
public class User1 {
    private String first_name, last_name;
    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
}
```

The error arises in the following:

```
void exchangeData(){
    users = users_;
}
```

The error being:

Required: `List <User1>`, Found: `List <User2>`

Even

```
void exchange(){
    users.clear();
    users.addAll(users_);
}
```

raises the same error

Comment: Please show the code that tries to equate but doesn't do it right...

Comment: I have edited the question to cater for this

Comment: I think you have to either provide some conversion or even a cast from `User1` to `User2` or you rethink your modelling. Having two identical classes that are not related via an abstract parent or an interface are generally not a very good idea. What are the differences between those two user classes in terms of content?

Comment: in terms of content there is no difference. I came to this dead end because i needed to load a heterogenous adapter and to differentiate viewType i had to use instance of User1 and instance of User2.

Comment: OK, if you want to stick to this, then convert from `User1` to `User2` (or the other way round) by some method, maybe like `public User2 convert(User1 user)` where you just get/set the values. Keep in mind that this distinction (though none needed in terms of content) may cause trouble later on...

Comment: _They have been named differently only because i use them in a heterogeneous adapter and use instance of to ascertain view type_ - can you further explain, I don't really understand the reason why you need 2 distinct classes, seem to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me.

Comment: @Benoit - Hi. I have a heterogenous adapter in which i will load a horizontal and vertical view. The items in the views will have similar data structure i.e first name, last name, age etc, but the content will vary slightly. i guess the challenge really is i don't know how to load them differently into the view except by using instance of. Since i use instance of, i cant say instance of User1 returns Horizontal view then go on to say instance of User1 returns Vertical View as well, so instead i've duplicated User1 as User2 to draw this difference. Does that make any sense?

Comment: But you can have 2 different lists containing same object types, i.e.:
`List<User> usersInHorizontalView` and `List<User> usersInVerticalView`.

Comment: This may not be your answer but I suggest you to use same adapter and different data types inside it. This example may help: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Heterogenous-ListView

Comment: Make it universal. Current one is not Best Practice and cause worse effect in long-term

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface User (with the getters and setters you want) and make both User1 and User2 implement this interface.

Now (if I understand the question correctly), instead of `List<User1>` and `List <User2>` just use `List<User>` to compare them.

Also why are you mixing camel and snake case? Surely you want `getFirstName()` instead of `getFirst_name()`? Makes my eyes bleed.